# using delegates in an array initialization

Tags: c#, arrays, function, struct, delegates

I'm coding a server and I've set up a TCP connection with all the clients.
Now, when a Client sends a packet I check the opcode of the packet so I can process it.

At the moment, I have an OpcodeHandler struct that currently contains `String name` but I also want it to have a C++-typed function pointer that calls another function, so that when I create an array with the struct as type and I initialize the array like this:

```
opcodes = new OpcodeHandler[max_opcodes] 
{
  new OpcodeHandler("someopcodenamehere", Somefunctionname);
  // more new's..
}
```

That the function named in the second argument of the constructor : 'Somefunctionname' gets called when calling the function pointer.
I've heard that this is possible with delegates since they behave just like function pointers in C++, but all of my tries were useless.

Comment: And what would be the signature of the function?

Comment: a void return type, with one argument : (Packet data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you have a struct `OpcodeHandler` that you want to create an array of.

Now I don't know what else the `OpcodeHandler` does, but I'll suggest something simpler:

```
Dictionary<string, Action<PacketData>> OpcodeHandlers = new Dictionary<string, Action<PacketData>>();
```

This is a dictionary of delegates.

You can add functions to it like so:

```
OpcodeHandlers["someopcodenamehere"] = Somefunctionname;
```

and call the functions like so:

```
OpcodeHandlers["someopcodenamehere"](packetData);
```

**Edit:**
You can also fill the Dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Action<PacketData>> OpcodeHandlers = new Dictionary<string, Action<PacketData>>
{
  { "functionName1", function1 },
  { "functionName2", function2 }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new OpcodeHandler("someopcodenamehere", packetData => 
        Somefunctionname(packetData))
```